# Adding related entities better way

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

How to implement adding related `Role` entities better way? It would be nice to keep it inside of a form if possible or maybe if I add a method to an `User` entity directly... Is there built-in mechanism for it or what patter shall I use?

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->submit($data);
    if (false === $form->isValid()) {
        return $form;
    }
    $user = $form->getData();
    // Adding a Roles
    if (!empty($data['user_roles'])) {
        foreach ($data['user_roles'] as $value) {
            // Checking if a Role is present in DB
            $role = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Role::class)
                ->findOneBy(['role_name' => $value]);
            if ($role) {
                $user->setUserRole($role);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(
        [
            'status' => 'ok',
            'last_insert_id' => $user->getId(),
        ],
        JsonResponse::HTTP_CREATED
    );
}
```

Comment: What class does this `add` method belong to? Please ask a more clear question.

Comment: @Trix, I don't think you can help me...

Answer (score 1):

I've always worked like that and I've never had a problem. In fact, I don't even use symfony's forms because they're not that flexible. The best way to do it is the one that you feel more comfortable with. Just be sure to be clean and consistent.
Of course you can add a method to the User entity, but it's just a matter of modularization, that's not very necessary in this case.